# Cannot create user-defined password profile: KeePass2 says "enforced configuration", but I cannot find it

Tags: keepass, configuration-managment, password-generation

I'm using KeePass 2.54 installed on a server I'm not managing (please skip pointing out the security implications of it).
When trying to create a user-defined profile for the password generator from an RDP session, I see a message talking about *enforced configuration*, and I'm asked for an administrator password (which I don't have/know):

[image: KeePass2 popup windows about enforced configuration]

Reading about [Enforced Configuration](https://keepass.info/help/kb/config_enf.html), I checked for a file named `KeePass.config.enforced.xml`, but I could not find one; instead I only found `KeePass.config.xml` with this content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Meta>
<PreferUserConfiguration>true</PreferUserConfiguration>
</Meta>
</Configuration>
```

So my guess would be that KeePass2 saves my preferences in a user-specific file (known as "Local Configuration"), but *would not* overwrite the `KeePass.config.xml` file (known as "Global Configuration").

Actually I found `%APPDATA%\Keepass\KeePass.config.xml` that contains the predefined password generator profiles and other user-specific settings.
So it seems to be writable by my user.
I'm owner of that file and I have full access rights on it.

### Reference

I think ["Installation by Administrator, Usage by User"](https://keepass.info/help/base/configuration.html#local) should apply:

> If you use the KeePass installer and install the program with administrator rights, the program directory will be write-protected when working as a normal/limited user. KeePass will use local configuration files, i.e. save and load the configuration from a file in your user directory.

> Multiple users can use the locally installed KeePass. Configuration settings will not be shared and can be configured individually by each user.

So I wonder:

- Is it a configuration bug that prevents creating user-defined password profiles?
- Is it a software bug?
- Did I (or the administrator installing the software) do something wrong?
- Is there actually an enforced configuration (I think: *No*)?

### Related

Maybe you want to read [Password generation profiles sync](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/33cafc04/) and [#2826 Store Password Generator Profiles within the database](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/feature-requests/2826/), too.

Comment: I would be very shocked if KeePass2 stored anything in the Windows registry. In fact, the notification message specifically suggests it's a file not a registry key that will be written to.  Have you ran KeePass2 with elevated permissions so the configuration file can be created?

Comment: You missed the important thing: I'm *user*, not *administrator* on that machine. Also on another installation, I can add password generator profiles without administrator privileges. And I'm mostly surprised about the two close votes.

Comment: I didn’t miss anything i am suggesting you need to be an Administrator to solve your problem

Comment: On a different Windows 10 machine I have KeePass2 installed, too, and there I *can* save password generator profiles! As I pointed out in the question, those profiles *are not* saved in the config file in the program directory, but in the configuration file within `%APPDATA%`. And it seems user-defined configuration *is* allowed. So I don't see where the admin did enforce this restriction. Are asked in another way: *What should the administrator do then?*

Comment: An Administrator is supposed to rename the configuration file to KeePass.config.enforced.xml which is the reason it doesn’t exist in the AppData directory. The documentation suggests that if an KeePass2 was installed as an Administrator, then the configuration data is shared among all users on the system, have you ask the Administrator who installed KeePass2 on the system? A different system could have had KeePass2 installed as a normal user. Without more information I can’t fully explain the behavior.

Comment: On "you need to be an Administrator to solve your problem": I asked the question *after* having talked to the administrator saying he has no idea what's causing the problem. Your comment sounds a bit like "You'll have to find the solution to solve your problem". Of course that's not wrong, but also little helpful., being a [tautology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology).

Comment: [Triggers & passwort generator profiles in enforced configuration?](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329220/thread/f3a64df33e/#ed64/7fe7/d075) suggests that I can just edit the %APPDATA% file to add the desired profiles, but I still wonder what It's all about to ask for the administrator's password when the use can just edit the user's file.

Comment: I am still under the impression that this issue you describe isn’t a unprivileged user problem but that of a administrators problem. Which you might find as being unhelpful, but not every problem you will have as an unprivileged user, will be solvable by you.

Answer (score 0):

The discussion in [Cannot create new password generator profile in non-enforced configuration](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/e976b54caa/#a403) indicates that the effect is a mis-feature introduced in KeePass version 2.54:

> Password Profiles are stored in the enforced configuration file beginning with KeePass 2.54. See the Important section of the [KeePass 2.54 release notes](https://keepass.info/news/n230603_2.54.html). If writing to the KeePass program directory requires administrative privileges, they are also required to save password profiles.

So even if an enforced profile does not exist (making one assume that there is *no* enforced profile, and thus *no enforced configuration*), KeePass wants to create one.

Comment: What exactly is a “misfeature”? Your final response is that, “ Profiles are moved to the enforced config file. You can no longer use / store them in the user config file.”, which goes back to “you need an administrator account”.

Comment: The mis-feature is that an installation for all users cannot be used to let a user setup a password generator profile in their own user profile; the user would still require an administrator password, and then the profile would be visible for everyone. Also there is no gain in security, as a user could use a local portable installation of KeePass (possibly even weakening the security by using a vulnerable version of KeePass).